# Using ADO on HTML page

Tags: html, database, ado

Here's my problem: I need to show data from a database using ADO recordset on an HTML-page.
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
<!--
Function getData()
   set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("D:\WP\ADOmodel\ADOexamples.mdb"))
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from tab1", conn

do until rs.EOF
    for each x in rs.Fields
       Response.Write(x.name)
       Response.Write(" = ")
       Response.Write(x.age & "<br>") 
    next
    Response.Write("<br>")
    rs.MoveNext
loop

rs.close
conn.close
End Function
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="getData()" value="Get Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, I have an error: Server object needed. Please, help me to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the Server object the script needs to run on the server side rather than the browser side as you are doing here. You should perform a submit and have the script run on the server, outputting the results as part of the page.